# Matlab ICA with "rica" and "transform"

Tags: matlab, transform

I'm using MATLAB for some independent component analysis, and I just want a "common sense check" that I'm passing the correct things around.

My data has 3 clusters, and clusters well in some combination of variables (i.e. if plot variable 1 vs variable 2 it might cluster well) but then not cluster well at all when plotting others, (eg variable 1 vs variable 3).

I want to find the components that separate the clusters of my data the most, so I'm passing my data to rica, and then the output of rica to transform to visualise the transform, then getting the ICA's from mdl.transformweights.

Eg:

```
%glossing over the pre-processing of my data for brevity, but note I have 115 samples and 48 variables, that belong to 3 groups
dataoutput3 = data(1:115,1:48);

%do ICA
Mdl = rica(dataoutput3,3);

%Transform predictors into extracted features
z = transform(Mdl,dataoutput3);

%plot stuff
scatter3(z(idx==2,1),z(idx==2,2),z(idx==2,3),'g')
hold on
scatter3(z(idx==1,1),z(idx==1,2),z(idx==1,3),'b')
scatter3(z(idx==3,1),z(idx==3,2),z(idx==3,3),'r')

bar(Mdl.TransformWeights)
```

Does that look right?

Please note the documentation (below) refers to transform from rica.

Documentation:
https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/rica.html
https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/reconstructionica.transform.html